Next.js docker compose - passing environment variable during build time
Next.js app bundles the env variables during build time. That's why I need to pass env variables as args and used them during the build stage.
Now as part of the CD/CI pipeline I want to pass args dynamically via environment variables declared in compose.yaml.
However, the env variable from compose file are not read during build time. In fact, the terminal prints the following message:
time="2024-12-12T23:35:10-05:00" level=warning msg="The "NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_SERVER" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string."
Compose.yaml
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      args:
        - NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_SERVER=${NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_SERVER}
    env_file:
      - ./frontend/.env
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
      NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_SERVER: http://localhost:3000/
    ports:
      - 8080:8080

dockerfile:
FROM base AS builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY --from=deps /usr/src/app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY . .
ARG NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_SERVER
ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_SERVER=${NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_SERVER}
RUN npm run build

All works fine when I explicitly set the env variable in args but that's not the desired workflow.
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      args:
        - NEXT_PUBLIC_GRAPHQL_SERVER=http://localhost:3000/


If you're setting the variable with execution-time environment:, you don't need to mention it in the Dockerfile at all.

That's not true, I need to set variables in dockerfile specifically at the build stage otherwise it's not being picked up by next.js bundle

If the build system is picking up the environment-variable value and "baking it in" to the image, then it won't be able to react to deploy-time environment: settings.  You need to pass it in build: { args: } as you have in the last example, and you won't be able to change it after the image is built.  Other next.js questions I've seen around Docker suggest it may not be a good match for a "build once, deploy anywhere" workflow, questions seem to frequently revolve around changing these settings at build time or needing to rebuild the application image on database changes.

You need to distinguish between the environment(s) you are preparing for the build, for the container runtime, and for compose itself.
Docker compose itself, when it is first parsing the compose.yml file does not use the env_file: to expand any ${VAR} directives in the compose.yml - that directive is for injecting variables into containers.
As such, dockers own environment is the source of variables: A .env file in the same folder as the compose.yml, any environment variables that are exported prior to executing docker compose are the sources for variable expansion in the compose.yml.

Indeed, I needed to use a separate .env file for the compose.yaml itself
